# No keyboard backlight after Elementary OS install

Tags: keyboard, macbook, backlight

Just installed Elementary OS on my late 2011 Macbook Pro but the keyboard backlight is no longer on and I cannot find a way to turn it on. I have gone to keyboard settings and there is no option for illumination. Any help will be greatly appreciated! I am new to linux so sorry if the solution is obvious. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Dear precious Elementary OS developers maybe will be able to answer, but I doubt.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to actually press the key (F6) and hold it down. I was surprised to see the lights come up.

Comment: Thank you you beautiful human! They come on! I did try upvote your answer but my rep is to low but I appreciate!

Comment: I am delighted to have been of assistance. I love it when the suggestions work!